# Video Sitemap colon in name using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sitemap, hex

I am trying to make a video sitemap for video website. But I am facing a XMLExecption "The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name." This is because of colons (video:video) in the name.

```
XNamespace gs = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
                XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                    new XElement(gs + "urlset",
                        (from p in db.Videos
                         orderby p.video_id descending
                         select new XElement(gs + "url",
                             new XElement(gs + "loc", "http://www.example.com/video/" + p.video_id + "-" + p.video_query),
                             new XElement(gs + "video:video",
                             new XElement(gs + "video:thumbnail_loc", "http://cdn.example.com/thumb/" + p.video_image)                           
                                 ))).Take(50)));
     doc.Save(@"C:\video_sitemap.xml");
```

Please tell me how to add colons in the name to generate dynamic xml sitemap using LINQ to SQL.

Thanks and Regards.

**UPDATE:**

This Video XML sitemap should look like on the page:
[Google Video Sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80472?hl=en)

Comment: It sounds like you *actually* want a different namespace, but it's hard to tell as we don't know what the XML should look like afterwards. (Also, please format your source code. I'm sure you haven't *really* got it formatted like that...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Actually I am just testing to make video sitemap on localhost right now, so code is same like this except I changed to website url and tables entities. I just updated the question with Google video sitemap tutorial link, can you please take a look on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`video` here is the alias for a namespace. As per the example:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1"> 
   <url> 
     <loc>http://www.example.com/videos/some_video_landing_page.html</loc>
     <video:video>
       ...
     </video:video>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

So you just need two `XNamespace` values - one for the sitemap namespace and one for the video namespace:

```
XNamespace siteMapNs = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
XNamespace videoNs = "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1";
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement(siteMapNs + "urlset",
        (from p in db.Videos
         orderby p.video_id descending
         select new XElement(siteMapNs + "url",
             new XElement(siteMapNs + "loc",
                  "http://www.example.com/video/" + p.video_id + "-" + p.video_query),
             new XElement(videoNs + "video",
                 new XElement(videoNs + "thumbnail_loc",
                     "http://cdn.example.com/thumb/" + p.video_image)
             )
         )
        ).Take(50)
    )
);
```

EDIT: If you really want this to use an alias of `video` for the namespace, you can declare it in your root element:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement(siteMapNs + "urlset",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "video", videoNs),
        (from p in db.Videos
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this quick reply, Please allow me to check.

Comment: I tested it and replied to this question with output below, Please take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@Jon Skeet:
Your code generated this sitemap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/video/1-video_query_1</loc>
    <video xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
      <thumbnail_loc>http://cdn.example.com/thumb/7665518872558731.jpg</thumbnail_loc>
    </video>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/video/2-video_query_2</loc>
    <video xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
      <thumbnail_loc>http://cdn.jigers.com/thumb/6921835997871337.jpg</thumbnail_loc>
    </video>
  </url>
```

but It should be like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
      <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/video/1-video_query_1</loc>
        <video:video>
          <video:thumbnail_loc>http://cdn.example.com/thumb/7665518872558731.jpg</video:thumbnail_loc>
        </video:video>
      </url>
      <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/video/2-video_query_2</loc>
        <video:video>
          <video:thumbnail_loc>http://cdn.jigers.com/thumb/6921835997871337.jpg</video:thumbnail_loc>
        </video:video>
      </url>
</urlset>
```

video:video have colons and there should be a `xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1`
namespace in urlset..

Please take a look

Comment: Firstly, this isn't an answer - if anything, it should be an update to your question. But the important point is that this is semantically equivalent XML to the original. It doesn't matter where the namespace is first declared. We *could* add it to the root element, but you definitely don't have to.

Comment: I've added an edit to my answer to show how you can get that output if you're really that bothered.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing aliases with namespaces.

Figure out what the namespace for 'videos'. Create an `XNamespace` for it (like you did in gs).

Then do `videoNamespace + "thumbnail_loc"`.

Comment: Yes you are right, ` xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1"` is the video namespace for videos, but in sitemap there should be two namespaces like on this [Google tutorial page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80472?hl=en)